# Doctrine error with mapping

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, mapping

I'm making a project in Symfony2, I was creating entities and I've got a ManyToOne association and when I try do get data from the database I get this error:

```
The association Ueb\Creator\Bundle\ModuleBundle\Entity\GenericBlock#fields refers to the owning side field Ueb\Creator\Bundle\ModuleBundle\Entity\GenericField#idGenericBlock which is not defined as association.
The association Ueb\Creator\Bundle\ModuleBundle\Entity\GenericBlock#fields refers to the owning side field Ueb\Creator\Bundle\ModuleBundle\Entity\GenericField#idGenericBlock which does not exist.
```

I've got this class's:

GenericField

```
 /**
  * GenericField
  *
  * @ORM\Table(name="crt_generic_field")
  * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Ueb\Creator\Bundle\ModuleBundle\Entity\Repository\GenericFieldRepository")
 */
 class GenericField
 {
 /**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id_generic_block")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ueb\Creator\Bundle\ModuleBundle\Entity\GenericBlock", inversedBy="fields")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_generic_block", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false)
 */
private $idGenericBlock;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id_field_type")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ueb\Creator\Bundle\ModuleBundle\Entity\FieldTypes")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_field_type", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false)
 */
private $idFieldType;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="isRequired", type="integer")
 */
private $isRequired;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="field_name", type="string", length=40)
 */
private $fieldName;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="position", type="integer")
 */
private $position;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="field_description", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $fieldDescription;

/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="adicional_info", type="array")
 */
private $adicionalInfo;
```

And my class GenericBlock

```
/**
 * GenericBlock
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="crt_generic_block")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Ueb\Creator\Bundle\ModuleBundle\Entity\Repository\GenericBlockRepository")
 */
 class GenericBlock
 {

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="blockName", type="string", length=40)
 * 
 */
private $blockName;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="itemBlockName", type="string", length=40)
 */
private $itemBlockName;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="blockDescription", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $blockDescription;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="createdAt", type="date")
 */
private $createdAt;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="createdBy")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ueb\Accounts\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="createdBy", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=true)
 *
 */
private $createdBy;


/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 * 
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Ueb\Creator\Bundle\ModuleBundle\Entity\GenericField", mappedBy="idGenericBlock", cascade={"all"})
 */
private  $fields;
```

I've seen some questions with the same error and tried the suggested answers but none work so I don't know what else to do, it must be a stupid error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was some time ago but I concluded that `@Column` and `@JoinColumn` cannot be used together. If your filed is relation you should omit `@Column` there. For example:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id_generic_block") <--- ***remove this***
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ueb\Creator\Bundle\ModuleBundle\Entity\GenericBlock", inversedBy="fields")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_generic_block", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false)
 */
private $idGenericBlock;
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. I didn't know I could only have one of the annotations. :)

Answer (score 1):

Is very important that you understand that when you use Doctrine 2, you need to map relations with objects, you need to think the design of your entities in a object oriented way (not relational way), using compositions and aggregations to make the object relations. I strongly recommend you to read Doctrine 2 documentation.

For example, `GenericField` should look like this:

```
/**
 * GenericField
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="crt_generic_field")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Ueb\Creator\Bundle\ModuleBundle\Entity\Repository\GenericFieldRepository")
 */
class GenericField
 {
     /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Ueb\Creator\Bundle\ModuleBundle\Entity\GenericBlock
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ueb\Creator\Bundle\ModuleBundle\Entity\GenericBlock", inversedBy="fields")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_generic_block", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false)
     */
    private $genericBlock;

    /**
     * @var Ueb\Creator\Bundle\ModuleBundle\Entity\FieldTypes
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ueb\Creator\Bundle\ModuleBundle\Entity\FieldTypes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_field_type", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false)
     */
    private $fieldType;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="isRequired", type="integer")
     */
    private $isRequired;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="field_name", type="string", length=40)
     */
    private $fieldName;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="position", type="integer")
     */
    private $position;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="field_description", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $fieldDescription;

    /**
     * @var array
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="adicional_info", type="array")
     */
    private $adicionalInfo;
    ...
}
```

Is very important that you understand that `GenericField` does not has an `idGenericBlock` integer property, but an object of class `GenericBlock` named `genericBlock` mapped on the column `id_generic_block` (same with `fieldType`).

Oh, I noticed another issue with your entity: should `isRequired` to be mapped as `boolean`? Should `adicionalInfo` be `additionalInfo` (I think you are hispanic like me :) )?

Again, I recommend you to carefully read [Doctrine 2 documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/).

Comment: Thank you for the tips, specially changing the isRequired to boolean :)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should put the relationship mapping on both the entities.

Example

My Category Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="category")
 */
protected $products;

public function __construct()
{
   $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

My Product Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $category;
```

And You should even have method in product Category Entity

```
public function __toString()
```

Try following this

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

look at the Entity Relationships/Associations. It would sort you out